# Origin of "walk and talk"

Tags: etymology, phrases, phrase-origin

What is the origin of the phrase "(lets) walk and talk"?

I have heard this being said explicitly in conversation, for example, when you're having a conversation with someone but you also need to be somewhere else it's not uncommon to say something like "I have a meeting in 5 minutes, lets walk and talk"

I have also seen this in reference to a film making technique that is commonly used in shows like The West Wing, where characters are literally walking and talking

I'm wondering when this phrase was first used, and whether it originated from a single source?

Comment: I don't think it's an 'expression' as such, it's just that the two words are similar and sound good when used together in various different contexts.